# How can I shoot when I touch the Box Collider

Tags: 2d, unity, touch

I want to change the Computer Input to Mobile Touch Input, if I press Space Button it shoots but how do I change this [Code] to Touch Input ?

I want it to have it into void OnTouchDown() but what do I have to put into the if(...) in the ShootingScript if I want to have it for Mobile to work ?

Here is my Shooting Script and my Player Controller Script

ShootingScript:

```
public GameObject shootingBullets;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) 
    {
        Instantiate(shootingBullets, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

---

PlayerControllerScript:

```
public float jumpHeight;

void OnTouchDown()
{
    if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y < 0.001f && GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y > -0.001f) 
    {
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpHeight);
    }

}


// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.UpArrow) && GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y < 0.001f && GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y > -0.001f) 
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpHeight);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.DownArrow)) 
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(-Vector2.up * jumpHeight);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

So from what I understand you want to shoot using `OnTouchDown()`, well if thats what you want to do then you simply repeat what you did in the playerController class.

ShootingScript:

```
public GameObject shootingBullets;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) 
    {
        Instantiate(shootingBullets, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}

void OnTouchDown()
{
    //no if needed as it is only called when touch input is down
    Instantiate(shootingBullets, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

alternatively you could put it into the update function using the input class:

```
void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) 
    {
        Instantiate(shootingBullets, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
    else if(Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.y < 0.01f){
        //if the first touch on the screen is moving down start shooting
        Instantiate(shootingBullets, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    } 
}
```

With the that last bit of code I'm assuming that the `OnTouchDown()` is literally when the player is moving there finger down the screen. If it was just touching the screen replace that with:

```
else if(Input.touchCount > 0)
    //if the first touch on the screen is moving down start shooting
    Instantiate(shootingBullets, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

I think that solves your problem unless I've misunderstood your question :)

Comment: On your first Code ther happens nothing, I"ve done a Debug and it is touching if I press at it but it doesnt shoot why ever..

On your Second Code I get an Error it says the Array is out of the Range.

But I fixed it, the Code with just OnTouchDown() was correct. The bullets spawned in the Center of the Box Collider that I pressed, I just moved the Box Collider into the Player as child and now its spawns exactly from the Player, thanks for your help !